# Accessing which activities are launched when camera app is opened

Tags: android

Can someone please tell me how to get the names of the activities launched programmatically when I launch the default camera application on an Android phone?

I mean to ask how to get the names of the activities say, if I switch from Viewfinder, capturing, viewing the photo, switching to video camera and such things.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect your device to your computer and start up the Android Debug Bridge (e.g. from Eclipse or Android Studio), you can watch the internal logging that goes on inside your phone. Often it is possible to tell what the names of the activities are from watching these logs.

Comment: Is it possible to get those names programmatically though? So I can save it somewhere.